# Testing a Slick app with isolation

Tags: scala, testing, slick

What is the best practice for testing an app that uses Slick? Ideally, I'd like to remain compatible with generative testing, so my test cases should be isolated from one another. This seems to indicate that I either need to set up transactional isolation between test cases (rollback after each test case), or have each test case create and drop its own set of tables, with some kind of namespace separation. I'm also using Scalatest & Scalacheck, although I'm not sure if that's relevant. I'm pretty comfortable finding ways to test things, but I'm really struggling to find good documentation on how to accomplish this.

Comment: As based on JDBC, you could have a look at http://acolyte.eu.org/

Comment: For unit testing, I'm already substituting data access objects backed by regular collections instead of Slick-driven DB code. So that makes most of my tests good to go. This is specifically for the integration tests and unit tests of the data access objects, themselves.